# How i Update user credits with Model::factory()

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to update the UserCredits after a purchase. So if a user has 10 credits and wants to buy 10 more, then it only overrides the old credit score with the purchased credits.
The purchased credits should be added to the current credits and saved.

```php
//SET USER CREDIT 
$set_credit = Model::factory('UserCredits')->where('email', "$email")->find_one();

if (isset($set_credit)){
$set_credit->credits = "+15";
$set_credit->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are some issues with your code:

```
//SET USER CREDIT 
$set_credit = Model::factory('UserCredits')->where('email', "$email")->find_one();

if (isset($set_credit)){
$set_credit->credits = "+15";
$set_credit->save();
}
```

Try this instead:

```
  $userCredit = UserCredits::where('email', $email)->first();

  if ($userCredit){
     $userCredit->credits = $userCredit->credits + 15;
     $userCredit->save();
  }
```

Also, make sure that the credits column is int.
Models should be singular.

As @ceejayoz pointed out it is better to use:

```
$userCredit->increment('credits', 15);
```

when you want to add a number to a column so we are 100% sure that the column value does not change while you are adding $userCredit->credits + 15

Comment: `$userCredit->increment(15)` is safer, as it prevents a race condition where two simultaneous requests might update the credits balance at the same time and get mixed up. (It's also much cleaner code). https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, i fix my problem like your example but with Model::factory(); Example:

```php
    //SET USER CREDIT 
$set_credit = Model::factory('UserCredits')->where('email', "$email")->find_one();
    if (isset($set_credit)){
        $set_credit->credits = $set_credit->credits + 15;
        $set_credit->save();
         }
```

Comment: Don't respond with a question use the comments for that, people on StackOverflow will be unpleased :) Btw why do you use the Model::factory function, that is not something you should use outside tests or seeds

Comment: cose otherwise system not send information to db i dont know why and i make it like `Model::factory()` and all done .. thank you for your example i can continue with my script :) :)